# If..Then in jQuery to check for open slideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using 'slideToggle' to open a couple divs on a site and want to ensure all of the divs are closed before another is opened.  Is there a way to run a if..then to ensure a toggled div isn't open before opening another?

Here is my script;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
  {
     $("a#toggle").click(function() {
          $("#contact").slideToggle(500);
          return false;
 });
 $("a#toggle_about").click(function(){
          $("#about").slideToggle(500);
          return false;
     });
  });
</script>
```

Calling tag;

```
<li><a href="#" id="toggle">Contact Me</a></li>
```

And called div;

```
<div id="contact">blah, blah...</div>
```

And CSS;

```
#contact{display: none; padding: 7px; font-size: 14px;}
```

Thanks,

------EDIT------
This seems to work ok, I can control the transition by setting speed to 500 or 0.  It just seems like a lot of code for a simple if..then.

Thanks for the suggestions and possible solutions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
  {
     $("a#toggle").click(function(){
         if ($("#about").is(':hidden')){
            $("#contact").slideToggle(500);
    return false;
     }else{
            $("#about").slideToggle(500);
            $("#contact").slideToggle(500);
    return false;
         }
 });
 $("a#toggle_about").click(function(){
    if ($("#contact").is(':hidden')){
              $("#about").slideToggle(500);
              return false;
    }else{
              $("#contact").slideToggle(500);
              $("#about").slideToggle(500);
      return false;
        }
     });
  });
</script>
```

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/A5KBb/)**

Comment: You could use the :visible selector.

Comment: You could use show() and hide() instead. Then you could hide() all the elements before running show() on the single element.

Comment: Even with show()/hide(), I will still need a way to check if the div is already open or not.

Comment: @Mgfranz In your question it says that you needed to make sure that all the divs are closed before another is opened. That doesn't require you to know if the div is open or not. Is there another reason?

Comment: @MiniRagnarok, with slideToggle(), it keeps the called div open until the href is clicked again, I want to verify a div is closed before calling another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add appropriate classes to your html and change the href to target the div it needs to open, you can significantly simplify your code.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="toggler">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" class="toggler">About Me</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="contact" class="toggleable">blah, blah...</div>
<div id="about" class="toggleable">blah, blah...</div>
```

Now you can handle both links with a single event.

```
$(".toggler").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".toggleable").not(target).hide();
    $(target).slideToggle();
});
```

the end result is when you click on "Contact Me", about will hide if it is open, and contact will show if it is hidden or hide if it is shown.

http://jsfiddle.net/nYLvw/

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a helper function to collapse any visible elements with a certain class, and then call that every time you're about to toggle a div.

The markup:

```
<div id="contact" class="toggle-content">blah, blah...</div>
```

The code:

```
function hideToggleContent() {
    $('.toggle-content:visible').slideUp( 500 );
}

$(function() {
    $("#toggle").click( function() { 
        var isVisible = $("#contact").is(':visible');
        hideToggleContent();

        if( isVisible ) {
            return false;
        }

        $("#contact").slideDown( 500 );
        return false;
    });
    $("#toggle_about").click( function() {
        var isVisible = $("#about").is(':visible');
        hideToggleContent();

        if( isVisible ) {
            return false;
        }

        $("#about").slideDown( 500 );
        return false;
    });
});
```

You might also check out the jQuery UI accordion, it's default behavior accomplishes the same. http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: .accordion could work nicely since the ui is already loaded.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Added Fiddle Link For Example

---

There are several ways to solution this problem.

Whenever you are tweening for effect, and you want to only tween if not already tweening, you will want to track the state of your tween.

Typically, you might have a trigger/toggler, and a target.  I like to use closures to accomplish the state tracking.  I might use something like this:

```
$(function () {
    // closures
    var $togglers = $('[selector][, selector]');
    var $target = $('[selector]');
    $target.tweening = false;
    var tweenStop = function () {
        $target.tweening = false;
    };
    var togglerClick = function () {
        if (!$target.tweening) {
            $target.tweening = true;
            $target.slideToggle(500, tweenStop);
        }
    };
    // handle the event
    $togglers.click(togglerClick);
});
```

[**>> SAMPLE FIDDLE <<**](http://jsfiddle.net/8dqGA/)